# Powershell - Replace recursively some characters in a Windows folder path

Tags: arrays, powershell, directory

I'm trying to build a Powershell script that allows to rename some folder that contains special characters.
I'm using a function that cleans the string and then rename the item with the correct name but I'm having issues when i try to get "deep" in the path.

Example:

```
$Destination="C:\Users\Images\blabla#\ecc&"
$folderspaths= Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination -Directory -Recurse | Select FullName, Name 

$folders path gives me a series of path and the folder name. That's correct. But here's the "wrong" part:
(Sanitize is the replace function, that works like a charm with variable pathCheck)


foreach ($folderpath in $folderpaths){
  $TEMPORARYDEST= $folderpath.FullName
  $NewName= Sanitize -PathCheck $folderpath.Name
   
   if($folderpath.Name -ne $NewName){
     Rename-Item -$TEMPORARYDEST -NewName $NewName
     
   }else {
     Write-Host "No special characters found in $($folderpath.FullName)"
   }
 
}
```

It works because it renames the folders that contains special characters with "". But when I get deep, it faults.

Because I replace the special characters contained in the get child item but that array doesn't "refresh" so when i try to rename "ecc&" it expects to find the special characters in parent name folder.

Could you please help me?

Thank you.

Tried to replace bars with "" in order to clean the entire string but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recognized a mistake in my script. It worked fine while $NewName was always the same value. But it stuck in the while loop if not.

I'm not quite sure about your function but was able to solve the problem with this:

```
$Destination = "$env:temp\folder1"
$folderpaths = Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination -Directory -Recurse


while ($folderpaths){
        $NewName = $folderpaths[0].Name.Replace(";","").Replace("'","").Replace("-","").Replace("#","")
        if ($folderpaths[0].FullName -ne $NewName){
            Rename-Item $folderpaths[0].FullName -NewName $NewName
            $folderpaths = Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination -Directory -Recurse | where {$_.Name -like "*;*" -or $_.Name -like "*'*" -or $_.Name -like "*-*" -or $_.Name -like "*#*"}
        }
        
    }
$folderpaths = $null
```

Instead of the Sanitize function I just used the Replace function immediately when generating the $NewName and filtered later for only folder names with ; ' - or # in it. I think you don't need to filter for * since you cannot use that in a folder name. Maybe take a couple folders and try that one.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of foreach you could try to use a while function and redefine the variable after renaming.

In my example here I've got three folders stored recursive in C:\Temp.
I define $folderpaths once at the beginning and rename the first folder.
After that I redefine the variable but exclude the folder that I just renamed.
Maybe this approach may help you.

```
$Destination = "C:\Temp"
$folderpaths = Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination -Directory -Recurse | select FullName



while ($folderpaths){
        $NewName = "RenamedFolder"
        if ($folderpaths[0].FullName -ne $NewName){
            Rename-Item $folderpaths[0].FullName -NewName $NewName
            $folderpaths = Get-ChildItem -Path $Destination -Directory -Recurse | select fullname | where {$_.FullName -notlike "*$newname"}
        }
        
    }
$folderpaths = $null
```